# Apache http server dose not generate the "phpmyadmin" page

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

after installing the Apache http server and make sure it working.

Just added the folder of phpMyAdmin-4.2.0-english to the \Apache2\htdocs.
Renamed the folder to phpmyadmin.

while trying to view the page via `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php.`

the page is not generated as php page.

all i can see is a textual page. (the index.php content as a text).

Did i miss anything? there is anything else i should install?

Comment: Make sure that PHP is installed and that apache recognizes that `.php` files are to be executed as PHP and not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it using your package manager first.  Once you get that to work, remove it and use the install you downloaded.

Assuming you're using Ubunutu/Debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql mysql-server phpmyadmin
```